# detect windows 7 audit mode

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5

**Background**

OEMS, Sys Admins etc. often use [OPK](http://oem.microsoft.com/script/contentpage.aspx?pageid=565676) or [WAIK](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd349343.aspx) for mass installation. During this they often ship some pre-installed applications. The installations of such applications happen when Windows installation enters in [Audit Mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744337%28WS.10%29.aspx)

**Question**

Using c#, how do I detect that Windows is currently in Audit Mode?

Comment: Why do you need to know? coding a virus? @

Comment: @DavidePiras I just want to skip some actions when my application is running in audit mode. These actions are related to some kind of analytic and application usage behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the registry:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State`
   
  for something other than `IMAGE_STATE_COMPLETE`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Setup` for `AuditInProgress`

EDIT - as per comment:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE` could provide some information in this regard too...

For details see see

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721913%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd450713.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794046%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

Comment: You could also try looking at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE`, since there might be something else useful there.

Comment: during audit mode, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State` is `IMAGE_STATE_SPECIALIZE_RESEAL_TO_AUDIT` and  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status` is `AuditBoot` value `1`. Thanks for pointing it out. This should make me move ahead.